# IEventProcessor - Set offset

Tags: azure, azure-eventhub

We are using an EvenProcessor which are using the iterface IEventProcessor.
When I connect to our Azure Eventhub I always get "all" data, but I only want "live" data. Was reading about setting the Offset, using a DateTime but I dont know where. Have been trying around without and success. Is it possible? Attached some of the code below:
Greetings

```
    public class EventProcessor : IEventProcessor
    {
    IDictionary<string, int> map;
    PartitionContext partitionContext;
    Stopwatch checkpointStopWatch;

    public EventProcessor()
    {
        this.map = new Dictionary<string, int>();
    }

    public Task OpenAsync(PartitionContext context)
    {
        context.Lease.Offset = DateTime.Now.ToString(); // not working - still gives all data
        this.partitionContext = context;
        this.checkpointStopWatch = new Stopwatch();
        this.checkpointStopWatch.Start();
        return Task.FromResult<object>(null);
    }
```